# ActiveRecord::AdapterNotFound: database configuration specifies nonexistent mysql adapter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm facing this mysql adapter error while trying to run the application in the production mode.. Also encountered this while precompiling assets.

```
ActiveRecord::AdapterNotFound: database configuration specifies nonexistent mysql adapter
```

database.yml

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  host: localhost
  database: staging
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: root

 production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  host: localhost
  database: staging
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: root
```

In my Gemfile,

```
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'activerecord-mysql-adapter'
```

I've already got these gems bundled. What am I missing or working out wrong ?

Comment: And what is in `database.yml` file?

Comment: I've edited my question description with database.yml content.

Comment: I believe it should just say mysql

Comment: In the version you've posted, there is a space before production: in database.yml. That might be causing the problem. Remove the space!

Comment: mysql is the old gem. mysql2 is a better gem to use with MySQL

Comment: @DivyaShravanthi what does `gem 'activerecord-mysql-adapter'` do? couldn't find its repo

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following line from your Gemfile:

```
gem 'activerecord-mysql-adapter'
```

It is not needed. But the other line is correct. Then run `bundle install` again. I'm not sure what is causing your problem but I think it might be a problem of overlapping namespaces.

// Also you shouldn't use the same database for development and production mode.